# Jumping from start to end of code block - vim

Tags: vim, editor

How to jump from start to end of code block where code is not under {}.

Eg. I can jump around code like following using `shift + %`:

```
if (true) {
//do this;
}
```

But i want to do the same in cases like:

```
def some_func
 do this
end
```

around def and end.

Comment: which filetype is that? the `def ... end` ?

Comment: That looks like ruby. Don't forget to try out `[[` and friends. See `:h [[` for more information

Comment: yeah thats ruby.. and [[ , ]] are helpful but not exactly what i am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the *matchit* plugin (that ships with Vim, see `:help matchit`), you can define `def` and `end` as additional keywords to match with `%`.

If that doesn't suffice, my [CountJump plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script%5fid=3130) allows you to create custom motions and text objects for any pair of patterns.

Comment: are you sure it ships with Vim? I don't have it on my unix installation (7.4)

Comment: @mihai: It's located in `macros/matchit.vim` inside the runtime folder. Alternatively, you can get it from http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=39

Comment: ah, ok, it's in there...although you still need to copy it to `plugin` to make it working

Comment: @mihai, no, see `:help matchit-install`.

Comment: matchit worked like wonder. All i had to do was add ':runtime macros/matchit.vim' in my vimrc. Thanks a ton @IngoKarkat :)